# Kohana 3.2 useradmin routing issue

Tags: routes, kohana

I am new to kohana and am developing a simple application that is using the useradmin module from http://blog.mixu.net. I am having, what I think, an understanding problem. At present the action_index redirects to user/profile when a non admin user logs in. I want to go to a controller called home instead. I want to redirect to home/index.php

I have tried simply changing the redirect and this does not work. I am suspecting I need to do something with routes to get me to home/index but I can not work out what I should be doing.

I would really appreciate it if someone could steer me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

You said...

> I want to redirect to home/index.php

Not in Kohana you don't. Kohana uses the front controller pattern, which means your entire application is run through a single index.php file that ships with the framework. What you are saying you want cannot be done. There is no need to go to home/index.php using Kohana. What you *can do instead*, is achieved in 3 steps:

1. make a new controller called home saved to application/controllers/home.php
2. make a route and put it above the default route in application/bootstrap.php
3. redirect to this route from your other controller.

Your home controller will be something like this:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller 
{
    public function action_index()
    {
       echo 'Home Controller Index method';
    }
}
```

In order to test the controller above, you could use a route like the following. You would place this into application/bootstrap.php above the default route (near the bottom of the file.)

```
Route::set('home', 'home(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

You could then access the home controller's action_index method by browsing to either your_app_url/home or your_app_url/home/index ...

But we're getting ahead of ourselves. Before you try that, I **strongly recommend** that you read up on [how controllers work in Kohana 3.2](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/mvc/controllers) as well as [how routes work in Kohana 3.2](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing) as well as the user guide pages in general (don't miss the cascading filesystem!).

Next, download the Kohana 3.2 source files, make a dummy, empty project and create one new controller with one new route, and make sure you get that to work before messing around with mixu.net's stuff. That guy rocks but he's quite advanced.